# get the string from searchable multi column listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android i am using the search in my android using edittext search is working fine and code of search is as follow:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // When user changed the Text
        arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ..........
}}
```

I am using simpleadapter to display the data in listview having two colomn col1,col2
say:

```
arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(LabelUser.this, mylistData,
                        R.layout.two_col_row, columnTags, columnIds);
list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

on click of list:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String selectedFromList = (list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        System.out.println(selectedFromList);
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mysampleapp.DASHBOARDTAB"));

    }
});
```

And gives output as:

```
{col1=A K JOHN, col2=21.45}
```

My Question is how to get a string from above i.e. of col1

example var = "A K JOHN"

listview creation:

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                String[] columnTags = new String[] { "col1", "col2" };
                int[] columnIds = new int[] { R.id.column1, R.id.column2 };
                for (int i = 0; i < labelIdArray.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("col1", labelArray[i]);
                    map.put("col2", labelRateArray[i]);
                    mylistData.add(map);
                    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
```

Comment: Either you should create your own adapter with customized methods or you should split the string

Comment: can't we get column wise data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the value of first Column, I think the following code will work,

```
   String selectedFromList = columnTags[position];
```

Just give it try and tell if it worked or not.

Comment: nope, i have added how i have make multi-listing at the end of edited question have a look.

Comment: The problem is that after filtering the listview, when i click on any item i want original id(indexes) not newly created ids(indexes).

Comment: @AmitKoranne What do you get by using my answer. and also please dont post the fragments of code. Post the entire connected code, so as it would be much better understandable.